# go - serve contents from a zip file in http

Tags: go

i'm looking at `github.com/remyoudompheng/go-misc/zipfs` to serve content from a zip file in http.

this minimal example works, i can get a {FILE} contained in **files/archives.zip**:
  **`http://localhost:8080/zip/{FILE}`**

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "github.com/remyoudompheng/go-misc/zipfs"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    z, err := zip.OpenReader("files/archive.zip")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer z.Close()

    http.Handle("/zip/", http.StripPrefix("/zip/", http.FileServer(zipfs.NewZipFS(&z.Reader))))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

now, suppose that i want something like **`http://localhost:8080/zip/{ZIPFILE}/{FILE}`**
i'm trying registering a func but doesn't work

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "github.com/remyoudompheng/go-misc/zipfs"
    "html"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func servezip(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    zippath := "files/" + strings.Split(html.EscapeString(req.URL.Path), "/")[2] + ".zip"

    z, err := zip.OpenReader(zippath)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(res, err.Error(), 404)
        return
    }
    defer z.Close()
    http.StripPrefix("/zip/", http.FileServer(zipfs.NewZipFS(&z.Reader)))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/zip/", servezip)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

what i'm missing? can an handlefunc return an http.fileserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the handler that you create. Try changing the last line in servezip to

```
http.StripPrefix("/zip/", http.FileServer(zipfs.NewZipFS(&z.Reader))).ServeHTTP(res, req)
```